# Why does the routing between my two NAS devices change from an efficient route to an inefficient route after some time passes?

Tags: networking, home-networking, powerline-networking

I have two power-line adapters with a buit-in 3-port-switch. One adapter is connected to my router, the other to my PC and two NAS systems. When the PC and the two NAS are powered on, the first hour or so, the traffic between PC and NAS or between NAS and NAS follows the shortest path between the ports of the power-line adapter and I get the full gigabit bandwidth.

After some time passes though, I am seeing very slow transfer speeds between PC and NAS or between NAS and NAS and after further investigation it turns out that data is now sent to the other power-line adapter via the AC and then back.

Isn't traffic supposed to always take the shortest route in a cascaded switches scenario like this?

Edit: The two power-line adapters are devolo Magic 2 LAN triple. Router is an AVM FRITZ!Box 6660 Cable (router and DOCSIS modem). NAS are Synology DS420j and Synology DS1019+. PC is custom built and I'm using the on-board NIC on the MSI MEG X570 UNIFY board. OS is Windows 10 with latest updates and newest drivers. The router assigns IPs via DHCP and the IPs don't change between the scenarios. Both IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled. The problem occurs randomly, sometimes after half an hour, sometimes after 2h.

Comment: Odd. How much time passes? And can you edit your question to add specific device and model numbers are being used in this setup for the power line adapters and the NAS devices.

Comment: Can you share make / model of the power-line adapters, and IP address / network information for two systems (and the router) for the times when the system is working correctly and then for when they are working incorrectly?  A diagram might be nice also, but you were pretty clear.

Comment: Updated the question. Anything else I need to add?